# Is there a way that I enforce that PHP reports error if I use an uninitialized/undefined variable?

Tags: php, error-reporting

I made a huge mistake by mixing result with results and it took me around 4 hours to finally find the bug.

So here is the question, in PHP, is it possible that I can enforce PHP to report errors if I use an undefined/uninitialized variable.

thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Set error reporting to `E_ALL` and ensure that `display_errors` in `php.ini` is on.

**php.ini**

```
display_errors = On
```

**PHP code**

```
// If you cannot access the php.ini file
// you can do this within your PHP code instead
@ini_set('display_errors' '1');
error_reporting(E_ALL);
```

The default setting you have right now probably excludes notices, the kind of errors PHP raises on uninitialized variables, which could be something like this:

```
error_reporting(E_ALL & ~E_NOTICE);
```

Comment: Hello BoltClock,

Where is the best place I put the setting? I have a constant.php that is included by almost all php scripts. Is that a good method to insert the setting into that include file?

thank you

Comment: You can place it in a config file or constants file that you know will be included in all of your scripts.

Answer (score 2):

In a development environment I prefer using [`error_reporting(-1)`](http://au.php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php). Which reports *all* PHP errors.

Comment: +1 For the benefit of the doubt, this is equivalent to `error_reporting(E_ALL | E_STRICT)` as `E_ALL` by itself *does not* include `E_STRICT`.

Answer (score 1):

yes, use `error_reporting()` and set it to `E_ALL`, like this:

```
 error_reporting(E_ALL);
```

Answer (score 1):

Set error reporting to report all errors. Either in php.ini or at runtime using `error_reporting(E_ALL)`

Answer (score 1):

it already does report an error. something like this:

```
"Notice:  Undefined variable: a in C:\wamp\www\testcenter\index.PHP on line 40"
```

maybe you didn't go specific enough. but you should try `error_reporting(-1);` as as if enforces the php to show some recomendations. a piece from the php manual about E_STRICT errors:

> Enable to have PHP suggest changes to your code which will ensure the best interoperability and forward compatibility of your code.

just remember that `error_reporting(-1);` shows more errors than `error_reporting(E_ALL);` because `E_STRICT` errors are not included in the `E_ALL` constraint.