# How to correctly set error reporting in PHP code?

Tags: php, error-handling

Maybe this is a stupid question but I do not see how to fix it. I am trying to activate error reporing as suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3597766/is-there-a-way-that-i-enforce-that-php-reports-error-if-i-use-an-uninitialized-u), but using the following two lines in the PHP5 code:

```
@ini_set('display_errors' '1');  // <- line 12
error_reporting(E_ALL);
```

However, when running the code I get the following error:

```
Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_CONSTANT_ENCAPSED_STRING in XXX on line 12
```

I tried it with and without the at-sign. Maybe a difference between PHP4 and PHP5? Somethig else?

Comment: How do I function syntax? Function arguments must be separated by **a comma.**

Comment: Oh crap, I overlooked that. I new its a stupid question... Thanks for pointing this out

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You missed a comma

```
@ini_set('display_errors', '1'); <--- here
error_reporting(E_ALL);
```